# Gmaps terrain option grayed out when using custom layers

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I added a custom layer (Open cycle map) to the main map in a website. The custom layer is working, but in the dropdown (mapTypeControlOptions) TERRAIN is shown grayed out and not as a main item but as a checkbox (see attached image).

[image: gmaps terrain grayed-out]

Below the code for the map:

```
    var mapoptions = {
        scrollwheel: scrollzoom,
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['ocm', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,],style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
           navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT},
           streetViewControl: streetview, 
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           sensor: 'false'  
    }


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("advmap_canvas"),mapoptions);
    var markerArray = [];
var markerIDArray = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map.mapTypes.set("ocm", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            return "http://tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            name: "OpenCycleMap",
            maxZoom: 18
        }));
```

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to reload the page several times, now sometimes is grayed out, sometimes not. I'm wondering if it's a gmap connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

The terrain layer is not always available for all zoom levels resulting in a greyed out checkbox.

Try to check with a standard map at the same zoom level if the terrain layer is available or not.
The only workaround may be to zoom out.